# Why does subcaption not work when using caption?

Tags: subcaption

I'm trying to figure out why `caption` doesn't display `subcaption` code, even though the package description for `subcaption` says

> The package is distributed with caption.

Can anyone answer this? It seems misleading to say that it comes distributed with `caption`, when the code doesn't even load.

Comment: The `subcaption` package relies on and automatically loads the `caption` package, but the converse is not true. Thus, if you want to use `subfigure` and/or `subtable` environments, you must load the `subcaption` package; loading the `caption` package won't get the job done. For me, there's *nothing misleading at all* in the claim that "the [`subcaption`] package is distributed with `caption`". Indeed, I interpret this claim as follows: "Any TeX distribution that provides access to the `subcaption` package also provides access to the `caption` package".

Comment: I misunderstood the comment then. Thanks Mico, I'll answer my own post with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, `subcaption` loads `caption`, but not vise versa. I misunderstood the comment made on CTAN. Thanks Mico!